# batch - how to replace a word using a var

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I have a question about how I need to do something in batch.

I'm making a batch-file that will encrypt en decrypt messages

I'm having trouble with the decrypting. When you encrypt something a key is created that you can use to decrypt the message.

I have this code:

```
set de=%de:!de1!=a%
set de=%de:!de2!=b%
set de=%de:!de3!=c%
set de=%de:!de4!=d%
set de=%de:!de51!=e%
set de=%de:!de6!=f%
set de=%de:!de7!=g%
set de=%de:!de8!=h%
set de=%de:!de9!=i%
set de=%de:!de10!=j%
set de=%de:!de11!=k%
set de=%de:!de12!=l%
set de=%de:!de13!=m%
set de=%de:!de14!=n%
set de=%de:!de15!=o%
set de=%de:!de16!=p%
set de=%de:!de17!=q%
set de=%de:!de18!=r%
set de=%de:!de19!=s%
set de=%de:!de20!=t%
set de=%de:!de21!=u%
set de=%de:!de22!=v%
set de=%de:!de23!=w%
set de=%de:!de24!=x%
set de=%de:!de25!=y%
set de=%de:!de26!=z%
```

Which `de` is the var where the decrypted message will be? `de1` to `de26` are the keys that correspond a letter.

What I am asking is how to make it so that, for example if the message is 'hello', the encryption of that message is 12334, and the key is: h=1 e=2 l=3 o=4, it replaces the numbers with letters?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking, but I assume --relying on your example `hello` - you have a variable `de` with `12334` stored, and `de1` holds `1`, `de5` holds `2`, `de12` holds `l` and `de15` holds `o`; if this is the case, you simply need to switch immediate and delayed expansion, like `set "de=!de:%de8%=h!"`, for instance, so at first the line becomes `set "de=!de:1=h!"`, and then `set "de=!h2334!"`; anyway, instead of providing tons of `set` command lines, you should reduce the question to the core problem, namely the nested expansion...

Comment: Related: [How to create nested variables in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16964150/5047996)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a simple mistake, see `set de=%de:!de51!=e%` if you change that line to `set de=%de:!de5!=e%` then you should fix it. The reason why that line broke the code was because `%de51%` was an undefined variable, meaning CMD interpreted the command as `set de=%de:=e%`. This meant that CMD would interpret `%de%` as a literal variable of `de:=e`
Fixed code:

```
set de=%de:!de1!=a%
set de=%de:!de2!=b%
set de=%de:!de3!=c%
set de=%de:!de4!=d%
set de=%de:!de5!=e%
set de=%de:!de6!=f%
set de=%de:!de7!=g%
set de=%de:!de8!=h%
set de=%de:!de9!=i%
set de=%de:!de10!=j%
set de=%de:!de11!=k%
set de=%de:!de12!=l%
set de=%de:!de13!=m%
set de=%de:!de14!=n%
set de=%de:!de15!=o%
set de=%de:!de16!=p%
set de=%de:!de17!=q%
set de=%de:!de18!=r%
set de=%de:!de19!=s%
set de=%de:!de20!=t%
set de=%de:!de21!=u%
set de=%de:!de22!=v%
set de=%de:!de23!=w%
set de=%de:!de24!=x%
set de=%de:!de25!=y%
set de=%de:!de26!=z%
```

Working example:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call :decrypt 12334
echo %de%
pause
exit /b

:decrypt
set "de=%~1"
set de1=1
set de2=2
set de3=3
set de4=4
set de5=5
set de6=6
set de7=7
set de8=8
set de9=9
set de10=10
set de11=11
set de12=12
set de13=13
set de14=14
set de15=15
set de16=16
set de17=17
set de18=18
set de19=19
set de20=20
set de21=21
set de22=22
set de23=23
set de24=24
set de25=25
set de26=26
set de=!de:%de1%=a!
set de=!de:%de2%=b!
set de=!de:%de3%=c!
set de=!de:%de4%=d!
set de=!de:%de5%=e!
set de=!de:%de6%=f!
set de=!de:%de7%=g!
set de=!de:%de8%=h!
set de=!de:%de9%=i!
set de=!de:%de10%=j!
set de=!de:%de11%=k!
set de=!de:%de12%=l!
set de=!de:%de13%=m!
set de=!de:%de14%=n!
set de=!de:%de15%=o!
set de=!de:%de16%=p!
set de=!de:%de17%=q!
set de=!de:%de18%=r!
set de=!de:%de19%=s!
set de=!de:%de20%=t!
set de=!de:%de21%=u!
set de=!de:%de22%=v!
set de=!de:%de23%=w!
set de=!de:%de24%=x!
set de=!de:%de25%=y!
set de=!de:%de26%=z!
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this